# Can't print specific characters to console application

Tags: visual-c++, character-encoding, console-application

I can't seem to be able to print specific characters to the console (Win32 Console Application) even if I SetConsoleOutput(1252). I've also tried changing the 'locale' as well as changing the console font.

For example I'd like to print 'ã' which should be character 227 on codepage 1252, but the console app just outputs a plain 'a' instead.

There are a number of other characters that seem to differ from what I would have expected for [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) - e.g., Ò,Ó,Ô and Õ (# 210-213) all come out as plain O.

Here is a code snippet:

```
int main()
{
    locale::global(locale(""));
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1252);

    for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++) {
        std::cout << "  " << i << ":" << (unsigned char)i;
        if (i % 10 == 0) cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And here is the output (raster font): 
   [image: image capture of output]

EDIT: Based on Igor's suggestion below, I am also adding the results when using Lucida Console and Consolas fonts. Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem.

Character 227 remains 'a' rather than 'ã' in all three fonts.

Lucida Console font:

[image: Lucida Console Output]

Consolas font:

[image: Consolas Output]

Comment: Try changing the console font, say to Lucida Console or Consolas. I suspect the font you use simply doesn't have those characters. Open a console window, click the icon in the top left corner, choose Defaults > Font

Comment: Thanks Igor. I've tried all three fonts, but the problem remains in each of them (see edited question). Do you get a different result in your computer?

Comment: It works if you call both `SetConsoleCP(1252)` and `SetConsoleOutputCP(1252)`. I'm not sure why. Either one without the other is not sufficient.

Comment: Thanks - including SetConsoleCP(1252) in addition to SetConsoleOutputCP(1252) as you suggested worked for me as well. I'd love to understand why, but I am glad that it is working! Thanks.